# How to Update title tag with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am working on angularjs  website but i have problem with title tag
its not updating when i move from page to another page. but only when i reload the page it will be changed.
here ismy title tag content coming form php variable:

```
<title><?php echo $meta_title; ?></title>
```

i tried to add this directive

```
app.directive('updateTitle', ['$rootScope', '$timeout',
  function($rootScope, $timeout) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element) {

        var listener = function(event, toState) {

          var title = 'Default Title';
          if (toState.data && toState.data.pageTitle) title = toState.data.pageTitle;

          $timeout(function() {
            element.text(title);
          }, 0, false);
        };

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', listener);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

and change the title tag to `<title update-title><?php echo $meta_title; ?></title>`
but it did not work !
Is there way to let angularjs update or refresh this tag without reloading the page?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code

```
    app.directive('updateTitle', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', '$window',
  function($rootScope, $timeout,$window) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element) {

        var listener = function(event, toState) {
$window.document.title = 'My new title';
          var title = 'Default Title';

          if (toState.data && toState.data.pageTitle) title = toState.data.pageTitle;

          $timeout(function() {
            element.text(title);
          }, 0, false);
        };

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', listener);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: i add this code to my directive but still not working .. is there anything should i change in title tag? <title><?php echo $meta_title; ?></title>

Answer (score 0):

Just include the `$window` service and use it.

```
$window.document.title = 'My new title';
```

For example:

```
app.directive('updateTitle', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', '$window',
    function ($rootScope, $timeout, $window) {
        return {
            link: function (scope) {

                var listener = function (event, toState) {

                    var title = 'Default Title';
                    if (toState.data && toState.data.pageTitle) title = toState.data.pageTitle;

                    $timeout(function () {
                        $window.document.title = title;
                    }, 0, false);
                };

                $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', listener);
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

I've written a simple directive for the same i.e. for updating title based on the current view loaded.

https://github.com/sagrawal14/angular-extras/blob/master/src/directives/page/title.directive.js

You can use this directive anywhere in your HTML to update the title. So you title is not bound to the Javascript code instead it will be dependent on the HTML. (Separation of concern)

Comment: where to inclode it ?  my title content coming form php variable , i can not add it as "my new title"

Comment: i have add this code my my head tag but still not working